# How to detect if javascript is enabled in a feature spec

Tags: rspec

I have a test helper that needs to have a different behaviour if it is being used by a feature spec that has javascript enabled e.g.

I have a test like:

```
it 'test something', js: true do
   ... (code that uses javascript)
   special_method
end
```

and another test like this

```
it 'test something else' do
   ... (code that does not use javascript)
   special_method
end
```

and the special method:

```
def special_method
   ... (lots form filling)
   if js_true?
     find_button('Update').trigger 'click'
   else
     click_button 'Update
   end
end
```

where `js_true?` is some method that returns `true` if the calling feature spec has `js: true`. I need this functionality because when `js: true` the page presents differently and `click_button` no longer works.

There is some bug  which means when I try to use `click_button` with javascript enabled then I get the following error:

```
    Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
           Firing a click at co-ordinates [73, 700.5] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body.home-page div.cc-window.cc-banner.cc-type-info.cc-theme-block.cc-bottom.cc-color-override--1608664607 span#cookieconsent:desc.cc-message' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. 

If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
```

The error message does not help because there is no overlapping element, and the message does go on to say:

```
     # --- Caused by: ---
         # Capybara::Poltergeist::BrowserError:
         #   
There was an error inside the PhantomJS portion of Poltergeist. 
If this is the error returned, and not the cause of a more detailed error response, this is probably a bug, so please report it.
```

So until this bug is solved, I need a workaround to detect if javascript is enabled for the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Since the question has been updated to provide the actual error message driving the request for this functionality, we can see that the actual issue is an overlapping element. I know you claim there is no overlapping element and think this is purely a bug (which wouldn't ever be fixed because Poltergeist is deprecated), but from that error message there definitely is an overlapping element and from the class names of the overlapping element I would say it's a banner across the bottom of the screen asking the user to accept the fact that the site uses cookies (`save_and_open_screenshot` would confirm that).

Anyway, if you choose not to fix your test by doing what a user would have to do (accept the cookies banner) then you can use the current RSpec examples metadata

```
def js_true?
  RSpec.current_example.metadata[:js]
end
```

to determine whether or not you're currently in a test that has the `:js` metadata set on it.

I do want to stress one more time, the use of `trigger` in a test is a REALLY bad idea. It doesn't replicate what a user can do, will make moving to more modern drivers difficult, and can end up making the test it's used in pointless.

------ previous answer -------

Your question is confusing because you have a test with `js: true` metadata which means it should only be run for tests which support JS, but then in it you're calling a method that tries to do something different if JS is supported. How is it ever called when JS isn't supported?
If you are somehow calling it from a driver that doesn't support JS, all JS supporting drivers should respond to `wait?` with true so you should be able to do `page.driver.wait?` or you could use `RSpec.current_example.metadata` to determine whether `js: true` is set - however not all JS supporting drivers support `trigger` and you REALLY shouldn't be using `trigger` if you are testing an app (it's fine to use if just scraping data from a page). You're going to have much better tests if you figure out why you think you need to use `trigger` (which doesn't replicate user behavior) and instead replace it with the behavior a user could actually do.

Comment: @Obromios Updated the answer -  99.9% sure that's not a bug in Poltergeist you're seeing - it's just the normal behavior of the site you're testing.

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted your question.  Also, you also solved the root cause the the problem, I am pretty sure it is the cookie banner which is appearing as a side-effect of the test.  This solves quite a few other test problems for me, so that is great.

Comment: @Obromios Glad it helped and that you can solve the root cause - When you have free time you may want to start looking at updating from Poltergeist to more modern drivers - it's really equivalent to a 7 year old browser at this point in time (due to PhantomJS not really being developed in the last few years) - Try the `apparition` driver which supports most (if not all) of the features Poltergeist has - https://github.com/twalpole/apparition - or Selenium with headless chrome.

Comment: I have put this on my todo list